# How can I format date in Angular and TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table where it displays the date.

My table is showing both date and time, but I want to display the date only.

This is my code:

```
import {DatePipe, formatDate} from '@angular/common';
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

export class RegistrationModel{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    middleName: string;
    nickname: string;
    createdAt: string;
    applicantCV: string;
    mobileNumber: string;
    emailAddress: string;

    datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');

  constructor(response){
    //formatDate(this.createdAt, 'M/d/yy', 'en-US');
    this.firstName = response.firstName;
    this.lastName = response.lastName;
    this.middleName = response.middleName;
    this.nickname = response.personalData.nickname;
    this.createdAt = response.createdAt;
    this.datePipe.transform(this.createdAt, 'M/d/yy');
    this.applicantCV = response.applicantCV;
    this.mobileNumber = response.contactInfo.mobileNumber;
    this.emailAddress = response.contactInfo.emailAddress;
  }

}
```

[image: table screenshot]

Comment: The date pipe _returns_ the formatted string. It doesn't do anything to its input parameters. Your call to datePipe.transform is a no-op.

Comment: Why was `formatDate` commented out in favor of `datePipe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forgot to re-assign the `createdAt` variable after you transformed the date.

```
this.createdAt = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(this.createdAt), 'M/d/yy');
```

edit

It also seems that you have to first cast the createdAt to Date.

Comment: Except createdAt is a string not a date

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I guess you are right. To be honest i didn't even look at the `DatePipe` API before answering that

Comment: Wow, your solutions actually worked for me. Thank you so much. I'm new to typescript so I might have a lot of questions in the future. Thank you again